# No Route Matches [GET] "/exchanges/3/mark_arrival

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Still new to Rails, having a routes issue that I'm not sure the cause of. I've defined the following custom controller action in the "exchanges" controller:

```
  def mark_arrival

  exchange_id = params[:eid]
  @active_exchange = Exchange.find(exchange_id)
  active_order_field = params[:ordfld]    

  if active_order_field == "1" 

    @active_exchange.status_1 = "Step 3"

  elsif active_order_field == "2" 

    @active_exchange.status_2 = "Step 3"
  end

  @active_exchange.save
  respond_with(@active_exchange)

  end
```

I want to call this action with the following link:

```
<p><%= link_to "Arrived", mark_arrival_exchange_path(ordfld: "1", eid: @exchange.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>
```

I set up the following in routes.rb:

```
resources :exchanges do
  patch :update_ordid, on: :member
  post :mark_arrival, on: :member
end
```

When I click this link, I get the error: **No route matches [GET] "/exchanges/3/mark_arrival**

If I change the route from POST to GET, I get the error: **Missing template exchanges/mark_arrival, application/mark_arrival with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `method: :post` to your link, by default it makes a GET request

`<p><%= link_to "Arrived", mark_arrival_exchange_path(ordfld: "1", eid: @exchange.id), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>`

Answer (score 0):

you have defined your custom route for `POST`. but you are using the route with `GET`

change your route to `GET`

```
resources :exchanges do
  patch :update_ordid, on: :member
  get :mark_arrival, on: :member
end
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, when I do this I get the error Missing template exchanges/mark_arrival, application/mark_arrival with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.